# How can I train a neural network to detect subliminal messages?

Tags: neural-networks

Is there a way to train a neural network to detect subliminal messages? Where can I find the dataset on which to train the neural network?

If I have to create the dataset, how would I go about it?

United Nations has defined subliminal messages as perceiving messages without being aware of them, it is unconscious perception, or perception without awareness. Like you may be aware of a message but cannot consciously perceive that message in the form of text, etc.

There are two many types of subliminal messages, one which can be made through visual means, another which can be made through audio.

In visual means, I'm referring to these types:

1. Messages which are flashed for very short while on the screen.
2. Messages whose opacity is changed to blend with the background.
3. Messages whose colors are varied slightly to blend with the background.

Example of 3rd type of subliminal messages: if there is a background of red, on this can be shown a message made up of slight variation of red, as a conscious mind can't distinguish between such close shades of red, people will take the entire thing to be red block, but a subconscious mind notice the slight variation in color, register the message, because humans can see millions of colors.

Comment: You would find as many subliminal messages and normal (non-subliminal-message) images as you could, then train a classifier on those two sets.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the dubious nature of subliminal messages. You have to clearly define what subliminal is. In all your cases presented, a manual algorithmic approach would be better. An ANN would tend to average out the subliminal messages as noise, just as your brain would. In the case of #2, #3, it's a matter of contrast, in which case computer vision methods of bringing out low contrast details to the forefront combined with a manual algorithm (perhaps an OCR pass for content not expected to have text) would be the way to go. ANN are not magic bullets, and still need to be used appropriately.

Comment: By "dubious nature" do you mean they don't work?

Comment: @noviceFedora, sort of. There is research showing some effect, but minor and not toward anything a person wasn't already feeling actionable towards. Subliminal messaging effects have been exaggerated just like the effects of hypnotizing. All research I've ever read shows the brain keeps it's hold on the individual, and any attempt to influence them beyond surface level fails. Thus, it's dubious nature, refers to it's exaggerated impact, and thus a likelihood of exaggerated worry about the issue.

Comment: Note that this is similar to your other worry on EE stackexchange about the Fry Effect and it's potential usage to attack someone with voices and other auditory hallucinations. The things you read online about microwave induced auditory hallucinations are greatly exaggerated. In reality, such a thing is hard to control anywhere near that level, from a fundamental physics perspective.

Comment: I request you to watch these two videos of Derren Brown: 1. Tricking Advertisers with subliminals: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43Mw-f6vIbo      and       2. A Toy's Story: How to control a nation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EchfO2pjOrM              Both of these videos show how subliminals can be used to manipulate people, there are few other videos by other magicians and mentalists too, if you want I can find them, you might say they were staged but I don't think so. Would you please provide links to your claims that they minimal effect. From my experience I think they do work.

Comment: I don't know if you have seen my thread on Dream.In.Code.net or not, in one of my posts there I have explained my reasons for believing subliminals work. I think subliminals and hypnotism have to be tailored to specific individuals using details of the subject. I don't know what your background is, but if you don't have a background in human perception, neurology, psychology, it is unfounded to hold the belief that subliminals and hypnotism don't work. Maybe the people who use these technologies spread misinformation to keep people defenseless.

Comment: Unless you don't trust the establishment, I'd suggest reading into any and all whitepapers, peer reviewed research, on the subject. Yes, hypnotist and mentalist, subliminal messaging...etc, can indeed be staged, and the usefulness can be exaggerated. Don't rely on youtube videos, shows, or other things, with no evidence of controls, process, and proof to be your guide.

Comment: " but if you don't have a background in human perception, neurology, psychology, " That is an attempt at argument by authority. A claim should be able to stand on it's own, you can't brush off someone's criticism by only stating they don't have the required credentials. I have a background in electrical engineering, signals processing, and have taken a fair amount of courses on neurology, psychology, and human perception (I'm fairly big into transhumanism, so it's in my area of interest)... yet, my credentials, nor your credentials matter here. You're making the claim, the onus is on you.

Comment: Would you please provide me links to whitepapers, peer reviewed research which formed your opinion about hypnotism and subliminals having mariginal effect. If subliminals utilized personal details of a person, like their loved one's name, significant events in ones life, they might work.

Comment: The best would be if you have access to a University research portal, as most will exist behind paywalls. However, Google Scholar would be a good start for your research efforts. Just be careful to make sure the paper you read is peer reviewed, I am not sure if Google indexes pre-print papers and such.

Comment: Typing Google Scholar subliminals, showed me few links and all of them seem to confirm they work. It has to use a combination of technologies to make it work, like using binaural beats, brain synchronizing, etc.

Comment: Please post a link to a couple of them. I have a feeling you're just seeing an admission of existence and ignoring the efficacy. Keep in mind, I said exaggerated. Subliminal messaging is a thing, it's just not particularly effective.

Comment: I think this has to be reciprocal, I have given you links to support my claim, you haven't given anything. It's true I had a cursory look at the results of the Google Scholars, would you please provide me your links, then I'll share mine. As Christopher Hitchens said: "What is asserted without evidence, can be dismissed without evidence." and "Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence". I have satisfied my burden for proof from my links. Would you please satisfy your burden of proof with your links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103625/discussion-between-jarrod-christman-and-novicefedora).

Comment: Maybe tomorrow same time.